# Как сделать проверку на существование канала в Telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

В коде только присоединение к самому каналу.

```
url_rec = messages[0].reply_markup.rows[0].buttons[0].url
client(JoinChannelRequest(url_rec))
button_data = mes.reply_markup.rows[0].buttons[1].data
message_id = mes.id
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetBotCallbackAnswerRequest
resp = client(GetBotCallbackAnswerRequest(
   tegmo,
   message_id,
   data=button_data
   ))
print("applyjoin")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению, не могу сказать точно, ибо не вижу весь код, но, полагаю, для этого можно использовать конструкцию

```
try:
    ...
except:
    ...
```

Уверен, телеграмовский модуль вызовет ошибку, если вы попытаетесь подключиться к несуществующему каналу и в итоге можно сыграть будет на этом.

то есть в итоге:

```
try:
    {ваш код подключения к каналу}
except:
    print('Канала не существует!')
```

---

Всем добра-бобра!

Comment: Нет еще условие.
Если канал не существует то он его пропускал, а если он есть то заходил туда.

Comment: Тогда попробуйте записать в скрипт входа какую-то информацию, которая будет давать нам оповещение. Условно обновлять переменную